# Very slow INSERTs into a large MySQL table without an AUTOINCREMENT primary key

Tags: mysql, insert, query-optimization

I've recently noticed a significant increase in variance of time needed to complete simple INSERT statements. While these statements on average take around 11ms, they can sometimes take 10-30 seconds, and I even noticed them taking over 5 minutes to execute.

MySQL version is `8.0.24`, running on Windows Server 2016. The server's resources are never overloaded as far as I can tell. There is an ample amount of cpu overhead for the server to use, and 32GB of ram is allocated to it.

This is the table I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE `saved_segment` (
  `recording_id`        bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `index`               bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start_filetime`      bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end_filetime`        bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `offset_and_size`     bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '18446744073709551615',
  `storage_id`          tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`recording_id`,`index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The table has no other indices or foreign keys, nor is it used as a reference for a foreign key in any other table. The entire table size is approximately 20GB with around 281M rows, which doesn't strike me as too large.

The table is used almost entirely read-only, with up to 1000 reads per second. All of these reads happen in simple SELECT queries, not in complex transactions, and they utilize the primary key index efficiently. There are very few, if any, concurrent writes to this table. This has been done intentionally in order to try to figure out if it would help with slow inserts, but it didn't. Before that there were up to 10 concurrent inserts going on at all times. UPDATE or DELETE statements are never executed on this table.

The queries that I'm having trouble with are all structured like this. They never appear in a transaction. While the inserts are definitely not append-only according to the clustered primary key, the queries almost alwayas insert 1 to 20 adjacent rows into the table:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO saved_segment
(recording_id, `index`, start_filetime, end_filetime, offset_and_size, storage_id) VALUES
(19173, 631609, 133121662986640000, 133121663016640000, 20562291758298876, 10),
(19173, 631610, 133121663016640000, 133121663046640000, 20574308942546216, 10),
(19173, 631611, 133121663046640000, 133121663076640000, 20585348350688128, 10),
(19173, 631612, 133121663076640000, 133121663106640000, 20596854568114720, 10),
(19173, 631613, 133121663106640000, 133121663136640000, 20609723363860884, 10),
(19173, 631614, 133121663136640000, 133121663166640000, 20622106425668780, 10),
(19173, 631615, 133121663166640000, 133121663196640000, 20634653501528448, 10),
(19173, 631616, 133121663196640000, 133121663226640000, 20646967172721148, 10),
(19173, 631617, 133121663226640000, 133121663256640000, 20657773176227488, 10),
(19173, 631618, 133121663256640000, 133121663286640000, 20668825200822108, 10)
```

This is the output for an EXPLAIN statement of the above query:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INSERT | saved_segment | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

These problems are relatively recent and weren't apparent while the table was around twice as small.

I tried reducing the number of concurrent inserts into the table, from around 10 to 1. I also deleted foreign keys on some columns (`recording_id`) in order to speed up inserts farther. `ANALYZE TABLE` and schema profiling didn't yield any actionable information.

One solution I had in mind was to remove the clustered primary key, add an AUTOINCREMENT primary key and a regular index on the `(recording_id, index)` columns. In my mind this would help by making inserts 'append only'. I'm open to any and all suggestions, thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I'm going to address some points and questions raised in the comments and answers:

- `autocommit` is set to `ON`
- the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is `21474836480`, and the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` is `134217728`
- One comment raised a concern about contention between the read-locks used by reads, and the exclusive locks used by writes. The table is question is used somewhat like a cache, and I don't need reads to always reflect the most up to date state of the table, if that would mean increased performance. The table should however remain durable even in cases of server crashes and hardware failures. Is this possible to achieve with a more relaxed transaction isolation level?
- The schema could definitely be optimized; `recording_id` could be 4 byte integer, `end_filetime` could instead be an elapsed value, and `start_filetime` could also probably be smaller. I'm afraid that these changes would just push the issue back for a while until the table grows in size to compensate for the space savings.
- INSERTs into the table are always sequential
  SELECTs executed on the table look like this:

```
SELECT  TRUE
FROM    saved_segment
WHERE   recording_id = ? AND `index` = ?
```

```
SELECT  index, start_filetime, end_filetime, offset_and_size, storage_id
FROM    saved_segment
WHERE   recording_id    = ? AND
        start_filetime >= ? AND
        start_filetime <= ?
ORDER   BY `index` ASC
```

The second type of query could definitely be improved with an index, but I'm afraid this would further degrade INSERT performance.

Another thing that I forgot to mention is the existence of a very similar table to this one. It is queried and inserted into in exactly the same manner, but might further contribute to IO starvation.

EDIT2:
Results of `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for the table `saved_segment`, and a very similar table `saved_screenshot` (this one has an aditional INDEX on an `bigint unsigned not null` column).

| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time | Update_time | Check_time | Collation | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| saved_screenshot | InnoDB | 10 | Dynamic | 483430208 | 61 | 29780606976 | 0 | 21380464640 | 6291456 | NULL | "2021-10-21 01:03:21" | "2022-11-07 16:51:45" | NULL | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | NULL |  |  |
| saved_segment | InnoDB | 10 | Dynamic | 281861164 | 73 | 20802699264 | 0 | 0 | 4194304 | NULL | "2022-11-02 09:03:05" | "2022-11-07 16:51:22" | NULL | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | NULL |  |  |

Comment: You've told us your table is subject to a heavy read workload concurrently with these inserts. It seems likely you have contention between the read-locks used by reads, and the exclusive locks used by writes. You won't see this contention in EXPLAIN output.. Can you please [edit] your question to show us some of the SQL in your read workload? It may, or may not, be possible to reduce that conention.

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: When the system is running slow, do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`  Look for any queries with a "Time" of more than a few seconds.  Let us know what they are.

Comment: Adding an AI PK is _not_ likely to speed things up.  Is `autocommit = ON`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added some more information to the original post. I couldn't find any slow queries in the processlist right now, but I will add it to the post if I manage to.

You mentioned read and write locks; I edited with my post with some more information regarding this, but it doesn't matter that SELECTs immediately see the most up to date inserted rows. I wonder if this could be incorporated to reduce this locking contention?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "saved_segment";  and the results of the 'similar named' table so we can see the scope of space used to support these two tables.  Page splits are likely to be significant over time.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I edited the post with the output

Comment: If inserting 10 rows takes 5minutes, I'd put my money on contention.  Have you profiled the reads as well as the writes?  Have you tried running `optimize` in case of fragmentation of the table?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: Slowlog --  lower `long_query_time` to 1.  (Nothing you have mentioned should take more than 1 second anyway.)

Comment: Is there much activity on `saved_screenshot`?  All tables share the buffer_pool.  A "table scan" on either of the tables you listed might flush everything out of the buffer_pool, leading to _all_ queries for the next several minutes being extra slow.  Note that mysqldump does table scans.

Comment: @GYY52380  Your TABLE STATUS reports look reasonable.  Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "%dirty%"; and B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "%dirty%;  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out on a limb with this Answer.

Assuming that

- The value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is somewhat less than 20MB, *and*
- Those 1K Selects/second randomly reach int various parts of the table, *then*

The system recently become I/O bound because the 'next' block needed for the next Select is becoming more often not cached in the buffer_pool.

The simple solution is to get more RAM and up the setting of that tunable.  But the table will only grow to whatever next limit you purchase.

Instead, here are some partial solutions.

- If the numbers don't get too big, the first two columns could be `INT UNSIGNED` (4 bytes instead of 8) or maybe even `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (3 bytes).  Caution the `ALTER TABLE` would lock the table for a long time.
- Those start and end times look like timestamps with fractional seconds that are always ".000".  `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` take 5 bytes (versus 8).
- Your sample shows 0 elapsed time.  If (end-start) is usually very small, then storing elapsed instead of endtime would further shrink the data.  (But make it messy to use the endtime).
- The sample data you presented looks "consecutive".  That is about as efficient as an autoincrement.  Is that the norm?  If not, the INSERTs could be part of the I/O thrashing.
- Your suggestion of adding AI, plus a secondary index, sort of doubles the effort for Inserts; so I do not recommend it.

**More**

> just push the issue back for a while until the table grows in size

Yes, that will be the case.

Both of your queries are optimally helped by this as an `INDEX` or, even better, as the start of the `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
(recording_id, index)
```

Re:

```
SELECT  TRUE
FROM    saved_segment
WHERE   recording_id = ? AND `index` = ?
```

If that is used to control some other SQL, consider adding this to that other SQL:

```
... EXISTS ( SELECT 1
        FROM    saved_segment
        WHERE   recording_id = ? AND `index` = ? ) ...
```

That query (in either form) needs what you already have

```
PRIMARY KEY(recording_id, index)
```

Your other query needs

```
INDEX(recording_id, start_filetime)
```

So, add that INDEX, *or*...

Even better...  This combination would be better for *both* `SELECTs`:

```
PRIMARY KEY(recording_id, start_filetime, index).
INDEX(recording_id, index)
```

With that combo,

- The single-row existence check would be performed "Using index" because it is "covering".
- And the other query would find all the relevant rows clustered together on the PK.
- (The PK has those 3 columns because it needs to be Unique.  And they are in that order to benefit your second query.  And it is the PK, not just an INDEX so it does not need to bounce between the index's BTree and the data's BTree.)
- The "clustering" *may* help your performance by cutting down on the number of disk blocks needed for such queries.  This leads to less "thrashing" in the buffer_pool, hence less need to increase RAM.
- My index suggestions are mostly orthogonal to my datatype suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I edited my post with some more information. While I think the improvements to the schema are definitely worthwhile, I'm afraid these same problems will resurface later when the table grows enough.

Comment: SSD or HDD?  If the machine has spinning disks, upgrading to SSDs might be enough to solve your current situation (too much data, 1K reads/sec + a few small inserts/second).  Will the 1K increase?  Are the Selects reaching for a scattering of `recording_id` values?